# Rendering Web Server Controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, render, webforms, asp.net-webcontrol

---

Is there a way to find out at runtime which is the context my web server control is running? I need to know at runtime if the web server control runs in mvc context or web forms context.

Comment: What do you mean by `server control`? There's no such notion in ASP.NET MVC. Please don't tell me that you are using classic WebForms server side controls in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Actually is not like that, not directly.. I have a TopMasterPage with WebForms in a dll and a SiteMasterPage in MVC with MasterPageFile pointing to TopMasterPage inside dll. TopMasterPage has a WebServerControl which obviously is not working and I want to change it's render in MVC context.